# uppercase and lowercase that condition the search

Tags: javascript

I enter the script

```
$('#editable').jMentions({
  source: function(prefix) {
    var dfd = jQuery.Deferred(),
        filteredUsers = [];

    $('.prefix').text(prefix)




    var users =  $.get('mention.php?elm=' + prefix, function(data) {
      data.forEach(function(elm) {
        if (elm.value.indexOf(prefix) != -1) {
          filteredUsers = filteredUsers.concat(elm);
        }
      })

      dfd.resolve(filteredUsers);
    })

    return dfd.promise();
  }
});
```

this script unloads me some results, these results are conditioned by what it types a user in a textarea, if in the database there is a user with for example the pinco nick, the user is forced to write pinco in the textarea, if he writes Pinco or PInco or PiNCO, I don't get any results, I would like the search on what a user writes is not conditioned, how could I do?

Comment: Make the data element and the input both lowercase. 
`if (elm.value.toLowerCase().indexOf(prefix.toLowerCase()) != -1) {`

Comment: covert the string to lower case before search eg var str =str.toLowerCase();

Comment: thanks  Vladimir Bogomolov